# Presenting geospatial data in Powerpoint

Tags: kml, powerpoint

I am looking for a more elegant way to display geospatial data in Powerpoint.  KMLs seem to be becoming the norm for quickly showing interactive geospatial data to colleagues and the general public. Is there a better way to integrate these incredibly useful KMLs into Powerpoint presentations than the example I've shown below?  Maybe there is a better solution for presenting geospatial data altogether in Powerpoint--I look forward to your ideas.

[image]

Comment: Save a Google Earth .kmz file on your computer and insert it as an object. When the Insert Object dialogue pops up choose Create From File and browse for the selected file. In PowerPoint, right click the new object and choose Action Settings. In the new dialogue, select Object Action and Activate Contents. Finally you might want to improve the visual appeal of the Object, which can be done using Format Object

Comment: @Mapperz good suggestions, if you add this as a solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerPoint KMZ/KML to Google Earth (via inserted object and hyperlinking)

Save a Google Earth .kmz file on your computer and insert it as an object. 
When the Insert Object dialogue pops up choose Create From File and browse for the selected file. In PowerPoint, right click the new object and choose Action Settings.

[image]

In the new dialogue, select Object Action and Activate Contents. Finally you might want to improve the visual appeal of the Object, which can be done using Format Object

Accept the Warning Notice
[image]

Answer (score 2):

While the question has been answered very well (and this is very late), here's an "aesthetic" solution for those getting here via Google (like me) that I just did recently for a Powerpoint:

(1) **Insert** screenshot of the KML in Google Earth to the Powerpoint 
(2) Right click the screenshot to add **Hyperlink...**

Answer (score 2):

You can put [Google Earth in your PowerPoint](http://interactiveearth.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-earth-in-powerpoint.html) presentations with Shape2Earth.

Answer (score 1):

[ESRI Maps for Office](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/esri-maps-office/index.html#/Welcome/029300000005000000/) is another solution to present geospatial data in Powerpoint. It allows you to use web maps from ArcGIS Online as dynamic slides within any PowerPoint presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .avi file instead of .kmz in Google Earth Pro (Pro is free now) and then easily add it to your PowerPoint presentation.

1. Have your .kmz with tour created and selected in Google Earth
2. Activate "Movie Maker" from "Tools" tab
3. In the "Movie Maker" window put a check mark by "Advanced" and then click "Record to AVI format."
4. Choose a resolution for your video and place where you would like to save your file.
5. Navigate using your mouse and keyboard as you normally do when viewing Google Earth.
6. "Stop Recording."
7. Done!

Answer (score 1):

In PPT, make a blank slide. Then go to Insert, and on the extreme right at the top  is "Screen Recording" with an icon. Shut all windows except Google earth where your Fly recording is. Back in PPT, click the Recording icon and a red dotted box appears along with the Google earth screen. You can move this dotted box to the area of the screen you want recorded. A small control box for the video appears at the top of your screen on top of the Google earth screen. In this box, either click the red dot "record" or simultaneously hold the windows icon +shift +R. When you are finished, click simultaneously the windows icon +shift +Q or move your cursor to the top of the screen and the Video Record box appears and you can click the blue square to stop. The whole recording then appears on the blank slide you were at in your PPT.